# I want to make my own version of (strlen) function...but why i am getting error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strlen(char *ptr);

int main()
{
    char string[] = "david";
    int a = strlen(string);

    printf("Number of characters is %d", a);
    return 0;
}

void  strlen(char *ptr)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        ptr++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: **Never say “I got an error” without telling us what the error is.**  Cut & paste the exact error so that we can see what it says.  If we can't see the error, we can't tell what the problem is.  It's like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "The car makes a noise" but not telling what the noise is.

Comment: The error is trying to use the return value of a function which returns `void`. And that's what the error message will say.

Comment: this isn't a rule, but `strlen` is the name of a standard library function, so you may want to rename it as a good practice.

Comment: @RinkeshP Note: C does have "7.31.13 String handling <string.h> 1 Function names that begin with str, mem, or wcs and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the <string.h> header."

Comment: Making your own `strlen()` function is fine, but know the inefficiency in counting a *byte-at-a-time* which only get worse as the length of the string grows. In the case of very long strings (1/2 Megabyte +), byte-at-a-time becomes orders of magnitude slower than the optimized versions provide by most compilers.

Comment: It's often good learning (and a bit of fun) to see how the optimized versions used in the current glibc, etc.. are written. GNU `strlen()` makes use of [Stanford Graphics - Bit Twiddling Hack - ZeroInWord](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord) to examine 4-bytes at a time -- only if one of the bytes is zero (the nul-terminating character). See [GNU glibc 2.36 - strlen.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strlen.c;h=54f3fb8167aed00f3422a0083b0591484e17ea1e;hb=89d40cacd0aed35e2546513ce01924b879523e46)

Answer (score 1):

> to make my own version of (strlen) function

OP's compiler is rightly complaining about return value to a `void` function.

Use the standard's `size_t strlen(const char *s);` signature with a non-`void` return.

`int` will handle the length of most strings.  `size_t` handles all strings and is the type used by many C library functions for sizing and string length.

```
// void  strlen(char *ptr)
size_t strlen(const char *ptr) 
{
    // int count = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        ptr++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Usage

```
//int a = strlen(string);
//printf("Number of characters is %d", a);
size_t a = strlen(string);
printf("Number of characters is %zu\n", a);
```

---

Candidate simplification:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s) {
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;
  while (*us) {
    us++;
  }
  return (size_t)(us - (const unsigned char *) s);
}
```

Pedantic: Works well with rare signed non-2's complement too.  OP's code can errantly stop on -0.

Comment: You first code uses `ptr` which is not defined   , and the `-0` claim is bogus; if the system allows negative zeros then they have to compare equal to other zeroes

Comment: @M.M `ptr` fixed.  C spec has `7.24 String handling <string..h>` ... For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).` so test for a _null character_ via `unsigned char *` is the compliant approach if `char`  as -0 is possible.  Access with `unsigned char *` also comes up in `strcmp()` with 2's complement `char`: compare should be done as `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strlen` function is defined as `void`, meaning it won't return anything. However, you are expecting to use the return value, and your function tries to return a value.

You need to define it as `int strlen(char *ptr)`, or even better, `int strlen(const char *ptr)` because you are not modifying the contents of `ptr`.

Comment: even better `size_t strlen(const char *ptr)` :)

Comment: sorry but my ques is different...i have uploaded a wrong code

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you need only one condition to make your strlen() is to know that any string is ended with `\0` so by using this information you can go through a while loop until you `str[i] == '\0'` that means you counted all characters in the string.

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int  i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int main() {
    printf("%d", ft_strlen("Hello world"));
}
```

I recommend running this example on this website to understand the code more by yourself [pythontutor.com](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)